# typecast on only one operand vs typecast on both operands

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard-2.0

Function **CarbonEquivalentFactor** below contained a bug where the result was rounded to the nearest integer, instead of a decimal value of double type.

```
public double CarbonEquivalentFactor(int fromNoCarbonAtoms, int toNoCarbonAtoms)
{
    return fromNoCarbonAtoms / toNoCarbonAtoms;
}
```

Adding a type cast to one of the variables works and the function returns a correct decimal value as a double

```
public double CarbonEquivalentFactor(int fromNoCarbonAtoms, int toNoCarbonAtoms)
{
    return (double)fromNoCarbonAtoms / toNoCarbonAtoms;
}
```

It seems logical that it would be correct to add a type cast to both operands, like below:

```
public double CarbonEquivalentFactor(int fromNoCarbonAtoms, int toNoCarbonAtoms)
{
    return (double)fromNoCarbonAtoms / (double)toNoCarbonAtoms;
}
```

However then Visual Studio gives me the IDE0004 hint, "Remove unnecessary cast". Compiling and executing the function with both type casts also re-introduces the same bug i.e. the result is rounded to nearest integer.

Why is this so?

The project is in .NET standard 2.0. I'm using MS Test framework 2.1.1 in a .NET Core 3.1 project to unit test the function.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(5, 1)]
[DataRow(3, 1)]
[DataRow(1, 3)]
[DataRow(0, 1)]
[DataRow(2, -1)]
[DataRow(-2, -2)]
[DataRow(3242424, 9343243)]
public void CarbonEquivalentFactorTest(int from, int to)
{
    var result = Emission.CarbonEquivalentFactor(from, to);
    var resultNET= emissionsNET.CarbonEquivalentFactor(from, to);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, resultNET);
}
```

The Emission class is a COM object in C++ and the other emissionsNET is .NET class ported to C#. The .NET function returns 0 when parameters are 1 and 3. And when having double type cast on both operands in division as below:

```
public double CarbonEquivalentFactor(int fromNoCarbonAtoms, int toNoCarbonAtoms)
{
    return (double)fromNoCarbonAtoms / (double)toNoCarbonAtoms;
}
```

***UPDATE***
It must have been something with my setup or some glitch in Visual Studio. Now I can't reproduce the above bug, and the function returns **0.3333** when in parameters are 1 and 3.
Anyway thanks for the time and help! I have at least sharpened my C# skills a bit today.

Comment: It isn't a bug, it a rule of [division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-) in C#

Comment: I made this unit test with `var result = (double)from/ to;` instead of calling the C++ method I don't have. The test passed. I also debugged and single stepped it and inspected the results. `[DataRow(1, 3)]` definitely returns `0.33333333333333331` for the .NET variant having two casts to `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# cannot perform an arithmetic operation on two values of different types. Here, a double division must be performed, since one of the variables has been cast to `double` and the other is `int`.

Therefore, a widening cast on the other (`int`) operand is performed automatically.

[Remove unnecessary cast (IDE0004)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0004) is just telling you that the second explicit cast is not necessary, because it is done automatically by C#. Therefore, the expressions with one and with two explicit casts are equivalent.

In fact, you can keep the second cast and the code will compile and work as expected. The hint just tells you that your code can safely be simplified.

See: [Type Conversion Tables in .NET / Widening Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/conversion-tables)

---

Quick test in C# Interactive window:

```
> 1/3
0
> (double)1/3
0.33333333333333331
> 1/(double)3
0.33333333333333331
> (double)1/(double)3
0.33333333333333331
```

Comment: If so, why is the bug re-introduced when the second widening cast is made explicit?

Comment: But why doesn't the (double)a / (double) b statement work as if a and b would be double types?

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a hint telling you that you can simplify your code. [Remove unnecessary cast (IDE0004)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0004).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes If I follow the hint and remove the double type cast, it will be the same as dividing two integers eg. 1/3 = 0 instead 0.333331. If I leave the both type casts there it will still return 0! That's the real issue. It only works when only one operand is typecasted (double)1/3 becomes 0.33331.

Comment: @JohanA I find it hard to believe, can you provide a snippet which reproduces the issue (including the caller code)?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic How can I best provide it?

Comment: You can add the actual calling code to your question or use a service like dotnetfiddle.net, e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDJsUy

Comment: @johana Could it be you are calling the function with `fromNoCarbonAtoms` set to 0?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic No the bug was with fromNoCarbonAtoms = 1 and toNoCarbonAtoms = 3.